# unable to insert into database using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to insert a query using the below jsp code

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*, javax.servlet.http.*" language="java"    
contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256" pageEncoding="windows-1256" %>


<%!public static Connection connect ()
{
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","dhawanbhai1");
} 


catch (Exception e)
{
//throw new Error(e);
return null;

}

}

public static boolean close(Connection c)
{
try
{
c.close();
return true;

}

catch (Exception e)
{
return false;
}
}
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head> 
<body> 
<form action=""> 
Please enter your username 
<input type="text" name="un"/>
<br> 
Please enter your password
<input type="password" name="pw"/> 
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html> 
<%
Connection c = connect();



String user=request.getParameter("un");
String pass=request.getParameter("pw");
PreparedStatement pst=c.prepareStatement("insert into userpass (id,password) 
values (?,?)");
pst.setString(1, user);
pst.setString(2, pass);


int val=pst.executeUpdate();

if(val>0)
System.out.println("Inserted record");
%>
```

but getting

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page 
/LoginPage.jsp at line 68

65: pst.setString(2, pass);
66: 
67: 
68: int val=pst.executeUpdate();
69: 
70: if(val>0)
71: System.out.println("Inserted record");


Stacktrace:
```

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390) 
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

```
root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 
'id' cannot be null

org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)

org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
org.apache.jsp.LoginPage_jsp._jspService(LoginPage_jsp.java:147)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be using scriptlets pal! Look into `EL 2.0`.

Comment: how do you access this JSP? Did you provide un & pw with URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the stack trace it says that the Column 'id' cannot be null. So the problem is probably that `request.getParameter("un");` is null. Check that you are passing the 'un' parameter and that you have the correct name 'un' in both places.

Change the bottom part of your code to look like this:

```
<%
String user=request.getParameter("un");
String pass=request.getParameter("pw");    
if (user != null && pass != null) {
    Connection c = connect();
    PreparedStatement pst=c.prepareStatement("insert into userpass (id,password) values (?,?)");
    pst.setString(1, user);
    pst.setString(2, pass);

    int val=pst.executeUpdate();

    if(val>0)
        System.out.println("Inserted record");
}
%>
```

When you first load your page 'un' and 'pw' will not be set, so it shouldn't be calling the insert method. This checks that the parameters are set before trying to insert it.

Comment: "un" is the username , so the jsp is supposed to take the username from the page.
but the problem i am facing is that it is not compiling and not letting me to the page where i can enter the values of "un" and "pw".

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 
'id' cannot be null

Comment: That is not a compile error, it's an exception. But I have updated the answer with how you could change your code to make it work.